# Tomat: start/stop/reload application by JMX? How to manage application's start/stop/restart by program?

Tags: tomcat, jmx

**Background:**
I have a task to `start/stop/reload` an application by `JMX` deployed in tomcat, jboss, weblogic or websphere. (One probably knows the mentioned web application servers already have manager page to implement it, we just want to concentrate all these four major web server admins' `start/stop/reload` feature by `JMX` into one page).

**Question with tomcat:**
I have an example application named `JMXWebExample1-0.1`. I could visit manager page by input of `tomcat/tomcat(username/password)` to the prompted login page, and I see the following link by clicking stop button beside the application name.

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop;jsessionid=49CDCBA3DDB3081BA3D6C5BCD9E4C8A3?path=/JMXWebExample1-0.1&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=59E98C1BA757DD3E7D9FDEA4504D3423
```

The link has `jsessionid=49CDCBA3DDB3081BA3D6C5BCD9E4C8A3`, and `CSRF token org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=59E98C1BA757DD3E7D9FDEA4504D3423`.

So when I invoke, `http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/JMXWebExample1-0.1`, it always give me 403 status code (Access Denied). **The question is** how I could stop application `JMXWebExample1-0.1` similar to tomcat manager page?

**Some steps before starting tomcat** 
I have following steps before the start of tomcat: 
1) Enable JMX by adding %CATALINA_OPTS%,

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

2) `tomcat-users.xml`: I put following configuration:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

3) context.xml which is under `E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml`, I comment following line:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >

 <!--  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" />  -->
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

**Updated:** 
`E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\conf\tomcat-users.xml`, when login, I use `tomcat`.

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script" />
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-jmx" />
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui，manager-jmx"/>
  <user username="both" password="both" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="role1" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="all" password="all" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-script,manager-jmx" />
```

In `E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml`:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >

 <!--  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" />  -->
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow=".*" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

Command to invoke:  `http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/JMXWebExample1-0.1`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, tomcat offers `HTML` and `JMX`interfaces that must be accessed in a different way.
you are trying to use the html one, for that you should send a POST request to

> http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/sample&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=A2D857324A2C4F5F3EAE0DE2934502BA

The /manager page is protected against CSRF with the `org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE` parameter. If removed, an error 403 is received along with an explanation:

> The HTML interface is protected against CSRF but the text and JMX interfaces are not. To maintain the CSRF protection:
>
> Users with the manager-gui role should not be granted either the `manager-script` or `manager-jmx` roles.

So, if you want to stop an application, send a POST request with a valid CSRF token.

**Stop an app through JMX**
First, you disabled authentication with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`, you may want to change that. `jconsole` can be used to control tomcat through JMX by connecting to a remote app at `<ip address>:9000` address.
Then, to stop an app use `Catalina -> WebModule` MBean, you will see several operation available, find `stop()` and use it:

[image]

Finally, as shown on [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Host_Filter), I think you should change the validation pattern or remove the `allow` attribute at all. Commenting the valve out probably disables the feature.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow=".*"/>
```

Also, [the role for JMX access](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) is `manager-jmx`.

Be aware of the security stuff here!

Comment: The solution does not work, I still got 403 Access Denied.

Comment: Add an UPDATE section to your question with your actual configuration.

Comment: Hi, Luis, Please see original question's update section. That's my current configuration of tomcat.

Comment: @user84592 Did you tried sending a POST with a valid CRSF token?