# Application not starting in tomcat 9

Tags: linux, tomcat, rpm

I have a web application running on tomcat6 installed as an rpm. This application starts its own tomcat instance.
In tomcat 6 it uses below script to start and stop the application:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat
```

We are upgrading to tomcat 9 and I don't see this file in tomcat 9.

I tried writing this script for tomcat 9 but it uses some other files like below

```
/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf
/usr/sbin/tomcat
```

These files are also not present in tomcat 9. I am new to tomcat. Could someone please suggest on what can be the alternative of `/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat` in tomcat 9.

Important: The application runs perfectly when it is deployed as war file inside webapps folder of tomcat.

Edit: There are multiple applications for which I want to start separate tomcat instance

Comment: Never, Never and Never user rpm packages for java base applications. please manual download tomcat  and install on /opt directory . now you can simplify modify your init script .

Comment: This is an existing web application and we do not want to make any change other than the changes required for tomcat 9.

Comment: Okey, that is exactly what i say, your setup is wrong.

Comment: Which operating system will be running on? You need to write a systemd service most probably.

Comment: @mah454: that is a matter of taste. Packaged versions of Tomcat have many advantages: automatic security updates, integration with the OSs startup system, a directory structure compatible with the File Hierarchy Standard, etc.

Answer (score 2):

From `RUNNING.txt` file inside tomcat installation

> (4) Start Up Tomcat
> On *nix:
> $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
> or
> $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start

Another alternative is to write a [systemd service](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-centos-7/). Example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and start tomcat with

```
systemctl start tomcat.service
```

To START and STOP application using JMX see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043012/2834978).

Comment: There are multiple webapps that work in similar fashion. I need a way to start and stop them separately.

Comment: There's no mention about that on your question though. You need the tomcat manager then.

Comment: Can we do it without tomcat manager? I believe I need to create startup and shutdown scripts inside /bin and change ports for application instance server.xml. But I am not sure what exact changes are required and what else apart from these.

Comment: [Here's my answer on doing that with JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043012/2834978). Forgot about that one so I was surprised it was mine :-)

Comment: If you **really** want separate JVMs for different applications you can use [`systemd templating`](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/). A `tomcat@.service` template is offered by [Fedora's package](https://fedora.pkgs.org/34/fedora-x86_64/tomcat-9.0.44-1.fc34.noarch.rpm.html).